# VB.NET Class Initialization and Functions

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop

Is there a way to call functions within a class upon instantiation of that same class?  Basically, I have functions within a class, but I want to automatically call some of those functions simply when there is an instance of the class created.

Basically, I have this structure:

```
 Dim instance as new class
 instance.function1
 instance.function2
 instance.function3
```

But I want this:

```
 Dim instance as new class
 'function1, function2, and function3 called by default
```

Comment: Nobody can possibly know what went wrong because the error can't be in any of the code you posted. Please post more complete code that includes the code where the error actually happened.

Comment: Stop adding question to your original question. we can't possibly know what is wrong with this... the problem could be anywhere...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you need to create a constructor:

```
Public Class MyClass
    Public Sub New()
        function1
        function2
        function3
    End Sub
End Class
```